# C++ [Warning] converting to 'char' from 'double'... But I'm not...?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, warnings

I have my own data structure defined:

```
struct Data
{
    int partNumber;
    char nameOfTool[ 30 ];
    int numInStock;
    double pricePer;
};
```

And I've got this function that is giving me problems:

```
void inputOrUpdate(fstream &toolsFile)
{
 int accountToModify;
 char nameOfTool[ 30 ];
 int numInStock;
 double pricePer;

 printf( "Enter record number ( 1 to 100, 0 to return to main menu )" );
 scanf( "%d", &accountToModify );

 if ( accountToModify > 0 && accountToModify <= 100 )
 {
      printf( "Enter tool name, quantity, cost" );
      scanf( "%29s %d %d", nameOfTool, numInStock, pricePer );

      Data toolToWrite = { accountToModify, nameOfTool[ 30 ], numInStock, pricePer };

      toolsFile.seekg((accountToModify - 1) * sizeof(toolsFile));
      toolsFile.write((char *)&toolToWrite, sizeof(toolsFile));
 }
 else
 {
      printf( "Invalid record number provided." );
 }

 printf( "\n\n" );
}
```

Specifically, this line:

```
Data toolToWrite = { accountToModify, nameOfTool[ 30 ], numInStock, pricePer };
```

Getting this error:

```
[Warning] converting to `char' from `double'
```

But this doesn't make any sense to me; "Data" should be int, a string of characters, int, double, and the scanf line should be capturing a string of characters, an int, and a double, and the line where I assemble toolToWrite should be expecting and integer, a string of characters, an integer, and a double... I don't understand where it thinks I'm converting a double to a char if I specified %29s in the scanf line; just %s fails as well.

I feel like I'm missing something extremely basic and it is driving me nuts. Any ideas?

Comment: It might be that the init list doesn't work with arrays perhaps. In the line you picked out the you put nameOfTool[30] which returns a single char.

Comment: your scanf is also wrong. should be scanf( "%29s %d %lf", nameOfTool, &numInStock, &pricePer );

Comment: Thanks! I knew I haven't quite mastered that yet. Still throwing the same error afterwards, but good to know, first time I've used scanf for multiple things.

Answer (score 4):

How about changing this line:

```
Data toolToWrite = { accountToModify, nameOfTool[ 30 ], numInStock, pricePer };
```

to

```
Data toolToWrite = { accountToModify, *nameOfTool, numInStock, pricePer };
```

Comment: I did try that, it gives me this: invalid conversion from `char*' to `char'. Which doesn't make sense to me either, but again, I could be missing something easy!

Comment: I modified my answer. added * so that it will become.  *nameOfTool

Comment: That took care of that, still getting this one: [Warning] converting to `char' from `double'. Thank you for your help so far!!

Comment: what compiler are you using? and version?

Comment: Bloodshed Dev C++ 4.9.9.2